# production.log in rails 3 is stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I have a weird issue on a test server...

basically my app is running fine, yet if i check production.log, it is for some reason stuck at yesterday, when i had an error on the app... since then, i have fixed it, deployed again, but the log still won't be updated. It's beel like that since yesterday night.

so if i try

```
tail -f log/production.log
```

the last log i see is from yesterday... what's going on? this is so weird O___o

here's from my log:

```
Started GET "/one" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2012-06-04 09:14:30 -0400
Processing by ParagraphsController#one as HTML
(0.5ms)  SELECT id FROM paragraphs WHERE length = 1
Paragraph Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "paragraphs".* FROM "paragraphs" WHERE "paragraphs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Rendered paragraphs/one.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
tail: cannot open `1' for reading: No such file or directory
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: .. even though I think I got the issue, what's that _cannot open `1` for reading_ error message? How exactly did you run `tail`?

Comment: you are right, by mistake i did: tail -f production.log 1 - however, when i typed tail -100 production.log i got the same (except for the tail error)

Comment: ls -lrt log the last file on the list is the more recently modified file. tail of that file and check to see if it is being written to.

Comment: tail -100 could b your problem

Comment: When you run `tail -100` that means you only want the last `100` lines and nothing more, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your log file has rotated? `tail -f` will follow a *file*, not a *filename*. If you want to follow the *filename*, then you should use `tail -F` instead. (Note the capital letter `F`.) This way, when the file is rotated, you'll get the new log file rather than stare at the old file.